# raise_FirstSetError in SpaCy topic modeling

Tags: lda, spacy

I want to create a LDA topic model and am using SpaCy to do so, following a tutorial. The error I receive when I try to use spacy is one I cannot find on google, so I'm hoping someone here knows what it's about.

I'm running this code on Anaconda:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re, nltk, spacy, gensim
# Sklearn
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation, TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from pprint import pprint
# Plotting tools
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def sent_to_words(sentences):
    for sentence in sentences:
        yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))  
 # deacc=True removes punctuations

data_words = list(sent_to_words(data))
print(data_words[:1])

def lemmatization(texts, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV']):
    """https://spacy.io/api/annotation"""
    texts_out = []
    for sent in texts:
        doc = nlp(" ".join(sent)) 
        texts_out.append(" ".join([token.lemma_ if token.lemma_ not in ['-PRON-'] else '' for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags]))
    return texts_out

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

# Do lemmatization keeping only Noun, Adj, Verb, Adverb
data_lemmatized = lemmatization(data_words, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV'])
print(data_lemmatized[:1])
```

And I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_regex_core.py", line 1880, in get_firstset
raise _FirstSetError()

_FirstSetError
```

The error must occur somewhere after the lemmatization, because the other parts work fine.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue and I was able to resolve it by uninstalling regex (I had the wrong version installed) and then running `python -m spacy download en` again. This will reinstall the correct version of regex.